# Mis tablas no existen en mi otra PC

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

He comprado una nueva PC y estoy instalando el xampp para continuar con mis programas creados. de mi antiguo PC he traido la carpeta "c:/xampp". ahora que estoy abriendo el "localhost/phpmyadmin" todas mis tablas me salen que no existen. ¿como podria hacer para recuperarlas?

¿en que parte de la carpeta que me traje("c:\xampp") de mi antigua PC estan las tablas con sus datos? ya que mi antigua PC ya esta formateada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Primero copiaste el directorio de `C:\xampp` y luego has instalado XAMPP  en la máquina? Si ha sido así siento decirte que es muy probable que tus datos hayan sido eliminados con la nueva instalación ya que uno de los pasos es inicializar el contenido del directorio de MySQL. Si aún guardas una copia de seguridad del contenido puedes parar el servidor MySQL, restaurar únicamente su directorio de datos y, por último, arrancar de nuevo el servidor MySQL.

Comment: Tal y como dicen, si aun posees el respaldo, o la copia de xampp, puedes probar de nuevo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia copie el directorio c:\xampp y lo puse en otra carpeta(cambie de nobre y ubicacion) en mi nueva PC, pero mi consulta tambien va por... que carpetas de esto que me traje debo pegar en el xampp instalado en mi pc nueva?

Comment: Creo recordar que el sitio web por defecto se almacena en `C:\xampp\htdocs` y que los datos del servidor de bases de datos MySQL se guardan en `C:\xampp\mysql\data`. Recuerda tener apagado el servicio del servidor MySQL antes de sustituir el contenido del directorio.

Comment: entonces reemplazo todos los archivos que estan en mi c:\xampp\mysql\data de mi nueva pc por los archivos de la misma ruta de mi antigua PC? con eso se restablecería?

Comment: Sí, pero recuerda parar el servidor MySQL antes de la copia y arrancarlo de nuevo tras terminar la copia de los datos. ¿Probaste ya a hacerlo? ¿Qué tal te fue?

Comment: ¿Qué tal? ¿pudiste solucionar tu problema?

Answer (score -1):

Para no complicarte lo mejor es que en tu pc viejo hagas copias de cada una de las bases de datos con la opcion export del phpmyadmin y luego desde tu pc nueva haces un import de esos archivos y ya esta!

Comment: Primero que nada, esto no es una respuesta, es un comentario. Segundo y aun importante, ya formateo la anterior computadora, por lo que no puedo exportar nada de ella.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: No me había fijado que la pc estaba formateada, y sugiero que en vez de criticar mis respuestas, mejor por lo menos intenten dar una luz al que hizo la pregunta.

Comment: @CamiloKent no estamos criticando nada. Yo reporte la "no respuesta", esto significa que la "respuesta", que es lo que hiciste, no es una respuesta, sino un comentario. Seguido, el moderador diamantado, vio que mi reporte es correcto, y esta avisando de lo mismo. Que debes hacer para no comerte una moderación, pues mover la respuesta a la sección de comentarios y ya.

Comment: Segundo, OscarGarcia ya había comentado correctamente, y yo agregué algo parecido en la sección de comentarios. El moderador diamantado solo paso por la moderación desde otro panel en donde no se vee eso.